# how to insert report part ion report using VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have created reports (ssrs 2012) using `VS2012`.

Some of those reports contain graphs I would like to reuse, so I published them using menu-item REPORTS - PUBLISH REPORT PARTS.

Now I would like to add them to the reports (in the same project) but I cannot find nowhere instructions how to do this???

I searched onlijne extensively, tried all buttons and menus I can find in VS, read half of the TECHNET (very educational btw) but all I can find is references to the INSERT REPORT PARTS button in ReportBuilder 3.0.......

Am I missing s'thing or is it not possible in VS2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that, though you can export report parts from VS2012, you can only use report parts when working with Report Builder 3.0.